# Correct way to catch error when await for function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch, settimeout, es6-promise

I can't catch reject in my function. I have searched at google, but I haven't found solution, so please help me with this piece of code:

```
async function errorFunc(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        return Promise.reject("Any error occured!");
    }, 1000);
}
async function main(){
    await errorFunc().catch((error)=>{
        console.log("E in catch:", error);
    });
    
    try{
        await errorFunc();
    }catch(e){
        console.log("E in try-catch:", e);
    }
}

main();
```

No one of that catch (in *main()* function) works...In console, there is simply printed (twice) this error message:

> Uncaught (in promise) Any error occured!

I want to catch that error (or better say promise rejection). How can I do that in my *main()* function?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `errorFunc` is not returning the Promise you reject, so it cannot be caught. Something like this should work `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject('Any error occurred!'), 1000));`

Comment: You are right, now it works. But - is there way to not return Promise? Why I dont want to return it? Because it is another "wrapper" which code makes less readable... I thought that when I declare function as "async", it automatically means it is Promise... So I can simply call Promise.reject() inside of it and it will behave just like normal promise...Is there way to do what I want? (use Promise.reject() without returning promise).

Comment: Yes, `async` makes it return a Promise. But if you don't use `await` anywhere in that function, that Promise is fullfilled immediatly (resolved, in this case). Whatever you do in the Timeout is no longer related to that Promise. Explicitly returning a "home-made" promise is needed if you want to keep a handle to it in your Timeout, so you can resolve it or reject it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
async function errorFunc(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject("Any error occured!"), 1000))
}
```

this is what you want.

---

```
setTimeout(callback, ms)
```

`callback` will be exec in global, no one catch it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it printed the same error twice, because in the second function:

```
try{
        await errorFunc();
    }catch(e){
        console.log("E in try-catch:", error);
    }
}
```

you printed "error" but caught "e", I didn't understand the issue that much but I suppose that that's the reason it printed twice,

maybe swap "error" with "e" to print the other error caught

Comment: This + what's described in 王仁宏's answer are needed

Comment: You are right, I have error there,  I should print "e" and not "error", but it is not what I am searching for...

Comment: Well I hope that helped,
As for the other question, I didn't mention it as I didn't know the answer but I thought I should mention it because you said it printed twice

Answer (score 0):

You must return a Promise from your function

```
async function errorFunc(){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
   setTimeout(() => {
      return reject("Any error occured!");
   }, 1000);
  })
}

async function main(){
   await errorFunc().catch((error)=>{
      console.log("E in catch:", error);
   });

   try{
      await errorFunc();
   }catch(e){
      console.log("E in try-catch:", e);
   }
}
```